# Where should i place methods that map my ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following ViewModel, which is the base class of other ViewModels that inherit it.

Is it a good idea, to place the method that maps the viewmdoel in the viewmodel it self?

Like this:

```
public class ShowQuestionViewModel
    {
        public ShowQuestionViewModel()
        {

        }

        public int Question_ID { get; set; }

        public Boolean Condition_Fullfilled;

        public String requiredmessage = "";

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dette felt er påkrævet")]
        public String Question_Wording { get; set; }

        public String Question_Type { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dette felt er påkrævet")]
        //[Digits(ErrorMessage = "Feltet må kun indeholde heltal")]
        public String Question_Number { get; set; }

        public String Left_scale { get; set; }
        public String Right_scale { get; set; }
        public int Scale_Length { get; set; }
        public String Left_Scale_HelpText { get; set; }
        public String Right_Scale_HelpText { get; set; }

        public Boolean Visible { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsAnswered { get; set; }
        public String Question_HelpText { get; set; }
        public String Question_HelpText_PDF { get; set; }
        public int Category_ID { get; set; }

        // Ting der er behov for til Views
        public SelectList Categories { get; set; }
        public SelectList Visibility { get; set; }
        public string RefUrl { get; set; }

        public void MapQuestionToViewModel(MvcApplication3.Models.Question question)
        {
            Question_ID = question.question_id;
            Category_ID = Convert.ToInt32(question.category_id);
            Question_Number = question.question_number.ToString();
            Question_Wording = question.question_wording;
            Visible = (bool)question.visible;

            String hlptxt = question.help_text;

            Question_HelpText = hlptxt;

            Question_HelpText_PDF = question.help_text_pdf ?? "";

            Left_scale = question.left_scale;
            Right_scale = question.right_scale;
            Scale_Length = question.scale_length ?? 0;

            Left_Scale_HelpText = question.left_scale_hlptxt;
            Right_Scale_HelpText = question.right_scale_hlptxt;

            Question_Type = question.Question_Type.type_description;

            Categories = GetQuestions.GetCategories(question);

            Visibility = GetQuestions.getVisibleSelectList();
       }
}
```

Or should it be placed somewhere else?

Links to some design-guidelines are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a second constructor instead

```
public ShowQuestionViewModel(MvcApplication3.Models.Question dbmodel)
```

The MvcApplication3.Models namespace should contain the view models and nothing else. I recommend that you move all business logic into a class library instead.

You don't have to take care of the mapping either. You could use a framework like AutoMapper or ValueInjecter.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by class library, and perhaps how you would map the ViewModel using this class library, with the above code?

Comment: A class library project in visual studio. Rightclick on your solution file in solution explorer and add a class library. It has nothing with mappings to do but with a good solution/application structure